# c# relation between two different datasets

Tags: wpf, datatable, relationship

How  can you create a relation between tables that are in two different DataSets and different classes?

Let's assume I have a table movies in my Main class and a table categories in a different class both in different DataSets of course. 
Is there a way I can bind them?

**My goal:** To replace the foreign key id_category in my Movie table with a name of a Category in a ComboBox column.

I will post the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what the DataGrid code could look like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MoviesCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MovieName}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesCollection}" 
                                DisplayMemberPath="{Binding CategoryName}"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CategoryIdInMovies}"
                                SelectedValuePath="{Binding CategoryId}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```